# Python не видит файл в папке

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пытаюсь отправить сообщение с фото в телеграмм боте. Мне нужно, чтобы он выбирал случайную картинку и отправлял пользователю. До этого прописывал полный путь и для случайной выборки ставил случайную генерацию на номер фотографии, но, это очень долго и слишком много для такого кода. Я решил, что получаемое последнее сообщение будет указывать имя папки. Но, таким способом у меня не получается отправить ни фотографию, ни файл. Пишет что её нет, и пишет какой нет.

```
def photo_send(message):
photo = open(random.choice(os.listdir('/home/mycomputer/Рабочий стол/Бот пиксель/' + f'{message.text}')), 'rb')
bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
```

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'цветы (6).PNG'

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Нет значит нет. Разберись в какой папке лежат файлы, а в какой они ищутся. Выведи, например, содержимое photo